# invokeChaincode returning ".protos.Response"

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, invoke, smartcontracts

I'm trying to invoke a chaincode from another to get some data that will be needed to do a specific function. When I do the invokeChaincode, I have ".protos.Response" as response and I don't know why.

My query function looks like this:

```
async queryFrigs(stub, args) {
    let first = "FRIG1";
    let last = "FRIG999";
    let it = await stub.getStateByRange(first, last);
    let results = [];

    while(true) {
        let res = await it.next();
        if(res.value && res.value.value.toString()) {
            let jsonRes = {};
            console.log (res.value.value.toString('utf8'));
            jsonRes.Key = res.value.key;

            try {
                jsonRes.Record = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
                jsonRes.Record = res.value.value.toString('utf8');
            }
            results.push(jsonRes);
        }
        if(res.done) {
        console.log('End of data');
        await it.close();
        return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(results));
        }
    }
}
```

And my chaincode, where I'm trying to call this query, looks like this (just to test, without your real function):

```
async sale(stub, args) {
    let frigs = await stub.invokeChaincode('frigCC', ['queryFrigs'], 'canal-frig');
    console.log('frigs.toString() >>>' + frigs.toString()); // prints .prontos.response
    console.log('JSON.stringify(frigs) >>>' + JSON.stringify(frigs)); // prints {"status": 200, "message": "", "payload": {"buffer": {"type": "Buffer", "data": [... buffer result correspondent to the data. ..]}, "offset": 11, "markedOffset": - 1, "limit": 689, "littleEndian": true, "noAssert": false}}
}
```

I would like to receive the data in its original format, without the conversion to buffer. Can anyone help me? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why not just return a plain object and not a Buffer? What happens when you try to return the results object instead of the Buffer?

Comment: Hello. I am facing this issue too. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `decode` the output using ledger proto

```
_ledgerProto.BlockchainInfo.decode(response.response.payload);
```

Refer https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/30749efdcc2e02d696520e709a1885846d57ba97/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js

Comment: This is the fabric nodejs SDK, not the nodejs shim package.

Comment: yes, you can reuse that functionality... need not need complete sdk